# Theorems and why do we calculate function sequences?

Tags: calculus

I know that the sequence of functions

$$f_k(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^k}$$ is convergent in interval [0,1].

But which theorems actually do you need to see that? and like.. why?

Me, who just "can see this" I just know it. But if I want to explain that to one of my students... or a friend.

Comment: I have tried to improve your title and text : in particular it is not a series (using a summation) of functions but a **sequence** of functions. Next time try to improve your formulation by yourself !

Answer (score 0):

For $0 \leq x <1$ $f_k(x) \to \frac 1 {1+0}=1$. For $x=1$, $f_k(x)=\frac1  2$ for all $k$. So the limit function is given by  $f(x)=1$ if $x<1$ and $\frac  1 2$ if $x =1$.

Let $0 <\epsilon <\frac 1 {1+e}$. If the convergence is uniform then there exist $k_0$ such that $|\frac  1 { 1+x^{k}} -1| <\epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,1)$ for all $k \geq k_0$. Put $x=1-\frac 1 k$ in this to get   $|\frac  1 { 1+(1-\frac1  k)^{k}} -1| <\epsilon$ for all $k \geq k_0$. Now let $k \to \infty$ to get $|\frac  1 {1+\frac 1 e} -1|< \epsilon$. This contradicts our choice of $\epsilon$.

I used the facts that $x^{n} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ for $0\leq x <1$ and $(1-\frac 1 k )^{k} \to \frac 1 e$ as $ k \to \infty$. The rest of the argument only uses  definition of uniform convergence. To show that the convergence is not uniform it is also possible to shorten the proof by using the fact that uniform limits of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: but what theorems do you actually use or need for this?

Comment: To see that the convergence cannot be uniform merely note that the sequence functions are continuous on a compct domain but the limit is not continuous on that domain.

Comment: I did not use any theorem except for the facts that $x^{n} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ for $0\leq x <1$ and $(1-\frac 1 k )^{k} \to \frac 1 e$ as $ k \to \infty$. The rest of the argument only uses  definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: @richardgayle I have added some clarifications on what results I have used.

Comment: But I would like to have a theorem. otherwise you can just made it up xD

Comment: Theorem: $(1+\frac x n)^{n} \to e^{x}$ as $ n \to \infty$ for any real number $x$. This is  a standard theorem found in  most books on Calculus. The fact that $x^{n} \to 0$ is by definition: $|x^{n}| <\epsilon$ if $n >\frac {ln (\epsilon)} {\ln x}$. @Felicia